Why is induced EMF in DC motor being included in Kirchoff's Loop Rule
I was reading some lecture notes (don't think I can include them here) that show the EMF induced in the armature of a DC motor, being included in the equation of Kirchoff's Voltage Law for the armature circuit; the armature circuit consisting of the voltage source, internal resistance, and windings of the armature.
But this triggers my spidey sense because induced EMF is exactly the one instance where the line integral of electric field (a.k.a. voltage) around a loop doesn't have to vanish.  What complicates it a bit is that the armature circuit is not precisely the loop in which EMF is known to be induced -- if it were, it would already be closed, and there wouldn't be room for the voltage source -- but as it clearly includes a good chunk, probably the majority, of that induction loop, I certainly wouldn't expect its net EMF to be zero.  Am I missing something, or what's the appropriate way to analyze this circuit?

Is this helpful? https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=MotorSpeed&section=SystemModeling

@BobD  Equation (4) in the link you sent is exactly the one that looks wrong to me, because it says that all voltages, including the induced emf, sum to zero.  My concern is essentially the same as in this question -- why do people seem to ignore that concern when analyzing the armature circuit?

Well..was the answer in your link acceptable to you and if not why not?

@BobD That answer makes sense, but then how should one properly analyze the armature circuit, if KVL isn't valid due to the presence of the induced EMF?

Imagine that you hold the rotor fixed, $\dot{\theta} = 0,$ while having $V$ impressed in the circuit, you still have $V$ in eq 4 working on the inductance and resistance of the rotor as $Ldi/dt+Ri=V$. So you can view the term $-K\dot{\theta}$ as the source of a current caused by the rotation that you would feel as a load working against your turning it with your hand when $V=0$. When both are  "on", $V$'s current is one way, and $\dot{\theta}$'s current is the other way.

@AdamHerbst Is my answer here of any help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598915/i-have-a-doubt-in-applying-kvl-when-an-inductor-comes-to-play-in-a-circuit

@hyportnex Okay that makes sense, I think I see the flaw in my reasoning, thanks.

@BobD  Yes that helps, and now I get the key point: when the loop is actually traversed by a material with non-zero but finite impedance, this impedance will ensure that the net EMF is zero, by limiting the current to the appropriate value.

The link How did Kirchhoff express his voltage law (KVL) may be of interest?  EMFs on one side of the equation and IR products on the other side?

Well, thanks to the helpful comments, I think I now see what was fundamentally tripping me up.  The distinction is this: yes, there can be a non-zero net EMF around a closed loop, but when there is a real (non-zero impedance) conducting material traversing that loop, this will almost certainly not be the case.  For that to happen, the loop would have to be in a vacuum or at least an insulator.  For example, if you put a wire around the loop, it will develop a non-zero current until the voltage across the wire's resistance balances the induced EMF.  In a sense, it is a back-EMF of resistance in response to the back-EMF of electromagnetic induction.  The fact that the armature circuit also includes its own voltage source isn't that relevant, it just modifies the EMF that the impedance must balance.  That's why equation (4) in Bob D's link lumps the voltage source with the induced EMF on the right-hand side, since both are essentially external sources responsible for the current on the left-hand side -- despite the fact that they counteract each other as hyportnex pointed out.


...show the EMF induced in the armature of a DC motor, being included in the equation of Kirchoff's Voltage Law for the armature circuit; the armature circuit consisting of the voltage source, internal resistance, and windings of the armature.

KVL is the modern formulation of a rule to write down circuital equations for schema-defined ideal circuits with ideal elements. It is about sum of potential drops, traditionally called voltages in circuit theory. Voltages in KVL thus reflect only integral of the conservative part of electric field, not net field, not induced field. There are no emfs referred to in general formulation of KVL.
KVL: Determine what the potential drop $V_k$ on each element $k$ in closed path is, and then sum of them is zero:
$$
\sum_k V_k = 0.
$$
For ideal inductor, potential drop on it is $LdI/dt$. This is because ideal inductor has to have zero field in its winding, so the induced EMF in it $\mathscr{E}_L=-LdI/dt$ has to be balanced by potential drop $LdI/dt$, to make integral of net electric field along the path that goes inside the winding, zero. For a real inductor with resistance and capacitance, this is not accurate, and potential drop on it has different magnitude than induced EMF in it.
So that is why for a circuit with ideal inductor, resistance and ideal voltage source with emf $\mathscr{E}$, the KVL can result in an equation like
$$
L\frac{dI}{dt} + RI - \mathscr{E} = 0,
$$
even though line integral of net electric field over the circuit (circulation of net electric field) is not zero. The first term is potential drop on the inductor, the second on the resistor, the third on the ideal voltage source(battery...). Thus we are not writing down integral of net electric field along a closed path, but we are writing down integral of the conservative part of electric field along a closed path, and that is always zero. Line integral of net electric field (or induced electric field) in the same circuit is $-LdI/dt$.

But this triggers my spidey sense because induced EMF is exactly the one instance where the line integral of electric field (a.k.a. voltage) around a loop doesn't have to vanish.

Yes, BUT: this line integral of net electric field (or induced electric field) around the loop, properly called net induced EMF in the closed path, but also often called "voltage", is not voltage in the sense of circuit theory and KVL. It is really the net induced EMF in the closed path, and is only (unfortunately) often called voltage for other reasons.
There is also the original Kirchhoff's second circuital law, which uses EMFs instead of voltages, and understanding it is very useful to make sense of KVL.
Kirchhoff's second circuital law: algebraic sum of all EMFs acting on current in closed path equals sum of terms $R_kI_k$ over all elements in the closed path.
$$
\sum_m \mathscr{E}_m = \sum_k R_kI_k.
$$
For the same example circuit, we have two EMFs: the induced EMF in the inductor, and the battery EMF. So this law implies
$$
-L\frac{dI}{dt} + \mathscr{E} = RI.
$$
This is the same equation for current $I$, only written with different signs and positions of terms.
Most of these questions about how KVL could be correct in presence of induced EMF are caused by the crucial misunderstanding of what "voltage" in KVL and circuit theory means. Let me repeat: it is not the integral of net electric field; it is the integral of only its conservative part.
